Closest attempt to making a Carnot Engine
My professor, a firm believer in electric cars, and I have engaged in a debate regarding the convenience of internal combustion engine(ICE) based vehicles in today's economy, (especially in my country). This discussion has led me to ponder: what if we had a vehicle powered by a Carnot Engine?
I understand that the Carnot Engine is highly ideal(hypothetical) in nature and is still not a 100% efficient. However, what has been the best attempt(highest efficiency) to making a real-life Carnot Engine or at least something close? To be more specific, what has been the most efficient internal combustion engine (ICE or IC engine), and where is it being used right now? (Also how was this achieved) Thanks!

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288985; https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56099; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/768895; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209034; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797920; https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/367022

Carnot engine requires you to wait essentially forever. Real world engines have to deliver sufficient power; they are often designed to work near maximum power output, which are endoreversible engines optimised for maximum power.

Note that the classical combustion engines follow the Otto Cycle  ( energyEducation.ca   or wikipedia )

Similar issues have to be solved for thermal pumps, used for building/water heating. A trade off between maximum efficiency (but near zero power output) versus maximal power output (but low efficiency).

This attempts to answer the question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114539/whats-the-efficiency-of-real-heat-engines

The real life inefficiency of the Carnot cycle has nothing to do with nonideality of the system elements or their frictional losses or other dissipative issues. The real life efficiency problem with the Carnot cycle is that its efficiency $\eta$ is constrained by the two temperatures between it operates, $T_{max}$ and $T_{min}$, namely $$\eta \le 1-\frac{T_{min}}{T_{max}}.$$
To achieve high efficiency in a heat engine one needs $T_{min}\ll T_{max}$ but if the low temperature is our environment, which is obviously the easiest, then $T_{min} \approx 270K$ and $T_{max} < 800K$, say, and then we get $\eta < 66\%$, no matter what we do, how fast or how slow, etc.
With other engines this is not the case. For example when compared to other engines, say one that converts electrochemical work (a battery) to electromagnetic work (dc motor), the problem becomes clearer. Assume an idealized case where some amount of electric charge, say, $z$ is transported from one electrode of a battery to another over an electric potential drop of $\Delta \phi$ and passed through the inductive coil of the motor while a weight $mg$ is lifted through a height of $\Delta h$, then if dissipative losses are ignored then $z \Delta \phi = mg \Delta h$, and the energy conversion efficiency is 100%. Here any efficiency losses relative to the 100% are due to friction, coil resistive loss, radiation, etc.
Note that for the battery-motor we measure efficiency differently because the quantity $zV_1$ where $V_1$ is the high potential has no physical meaning, only the potential difference $\Delta \phi = V_1-V_0$ between the electrodes has meaning. On the contrary, in the case of the heat engine the absolute temperatures do have an absolute meaning and we assume that the heat (or rather entropy) dumped at the low temperature is not reusable and measure efficiency relative to the absorbed heat (absorbed thermal energy carried by the absorbed entropy at $T_{max}$). The efficiency could be increased if the dumped entropy (heat) at $T_{min}$ could be reused with another Carnot cycle connected to an even lower temperature.
